# Row count of each file in a `.zip` folder

Tags: linux, unix, zcat

I have one zip folder with 5 text files inside. I have to check the row count of each file without unzipping the zip folder.

I tried `zcat file.zip | wc -l` but it gives the count of the first file only.

Can you guys help me to get the result as mentioned below:

```
File_Name Rowcount
file1 100
file2 100
file3 100
file4 100
file5 100
```

Comment: Is `file.zip` a `tar.gz` or MS-DOS `zip` file?

Answer (score -1):

If your file is a gzipped `tar` archive, then you can simply loop over each filename in the archive to get the number of lines in each. For example if you archive contains:

```
$ tar -tzf /tmp/tmp-david/zipfile.tar.gz
yon.c
yourmachinecode.s
zeroonect.c
zeros
zz
```

You can loop over the filenames with:

```
$ for i in $(tar -tzf /tmp/tmp-david/zipfile.tar.gz); do 
printf "%8d lines - %s\n" $(wc -l <"$i") "$i"
done
      61 lines - yon.c
       5 lines - yourmachinecode.s
      63 lines - zeroonect.c
       0 lines - zeros
       1 lines - zz
```

You can keep a sum and increment with each count as required to get the total.

If your file is a .zip (MS-DOS) archive, then you can do the same thing, but the parsing of the individual filenames from the output of `unzip -l` takes a bit more work, e.g.

```
$ unzip -l /tmp/tmp-david/zipfile.zip | grep -v '^-' | \
tail -n+3 | head -n-1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

(you would use the above as in your *command substitution* to drive the `for` loop)

Comment: Thanks for Replying , I tried this unzip -l /tmp/tmp-david/zipfile.zip | grep -v '^-' | \
tail -n+3 | head -n-1 | awk '{print $4}' . It is just returning the file names not the row counts.

Comment: @user9638443 -- Of course it is. Re-read the very last line in the answer `:)` As in `for i in $(unzip -l ..... awk '{print $4}'); do ...`